# Browserify bundle size with Ampersand / React

Tags: javascript, browserify, ampersand.js

I really like what I've seen so far with Ampersand JS & React.

But I've ran into deployment issue.

When I run test package from ampersand (quick start guide) the app bundle size is 455 Kb uncompressed / around 30Kb compressed. Which is great.

https://ampersandjs.com/learn/quick-start-guide

When I run browserify (same package) it's about 955Kb uncompressed and 255 compressed (I compress with minifyify). The problem is with browserify itself (uncompressed is twice as big), but it's recommended and I love it too.

```
browserify client/app.js -o ./bundle.js
browserify client/app.js -p [minifyify --no-map --uglify [ --compress ] ] > bundle.js
```

So something is really wrong with the way I approach it... can you help me on this?

Same about React ... official mi.js is twice as smaller than what I have when require React

UPDATE 1: after some research I got a feeling that same modules are being loaded twice. i.e. slightly diff. versions etc. I did npm dedupe - didn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

no issue - I found out that I had gzip disabled on local machine.

awesome tool though: https://github.com/hughsk/disc